# List of all ecommerce websites

Tags: data-request

I need a comprehensice list of e-ecommerce website. Specifically, this list needs to include both famous websites (Amazon...) and the mom and pop sort of websites, like the ones that use Magento, OpenCart...
P.S. It would be nice if the license was open

Comment: I don't believe that you will find a complete list of ALL the websites. Maybe a list with a few thousands would be more feasible. Or a complete list in base of a country.

Comment: Perhaps if you narrowed down your suggestion it would be easier to find some lists that would help you compile this.

Answer (score 2):

Based on checkout usability performance these are the top 100 E-Commerce websites

http://baymard.com/checkout-usability/benchmark/top-100